# How do I overload function to accept both async and synchronized version of callback parameter

Tags: c#, async-await, task, overloading, multitasking

```
public static T SyncVer<T>(Func<T> callback)
{
    using (new LogContext("new logging context"))
    {
        try
        {
            return callback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<T> AsyncVer<T>(Func<Task<T>> callback)
{
    using (new LogContext("new logging context"))
    {
        try
        {
            return await callback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Please consider the code above. You may see most of the code in both functions is the same. I am searching for a way to group them up by overloading them into one so that I don't need to duplicate the content.
Is there a way to take out the similar part of both functions?

Any help provided will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't try to square peg a round hole, just duplicate the very minimal code and be done with it. Wrapping your sync versions in a `Task.FromResult` will just cause unnecessary allocations, unless you're returning a very small subset of values, like `bool` and some small subset of `int`s

Comment: Take a look at [the flag argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
public static T SyncVer<T>(Func<T> callback)
{
    return AsyncVer(() => Task.FromResult(callback())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, upvoted. It should be noted though that blocking the async method with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` could lead to a deadlock, in case the `AsyncVer` contained also other awaited calls (for example an `await Task.Delay(1000)`) without `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and was used in an environment with a synchronization context installed (for example WinForms).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias fair point! Haven't done winforms in close to a decade :)

Answer (score 5):

Note that `Task.FromResult` will allocate, and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` may dead lock

Personally I would just create two methods and not worry about it.

However, another (and slightly safer) approach is to wrap your callbacks in a `ValueTask`. `ValueTasks` work best if they execute synchronously, however they have a few subtle limitations and should never be awaited more than once.

The assumption is, this is all about creation an *awaitable* and non *awaitable* delegate overload, code reuse, and awaiting the sync version of this call is not a problem for you.

**Given**

```
public static async ValueTask<T> SomethingAsync<T>(Func<T> callback)
 =>  await SomethingAsync(() => new ValueTask<T>(callback()));

public static async ValueTask<T> SomethingAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> callback)
 =>  await SomethingAsync(() => new ValueTask<T>(callback()));

public static async ValueTask<T> SomethingAsync<T>(Func<ValueTask<T>> callback)
{
   using (new LogContext("new logging context"))
   {
      try
      {
         return await callback();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
         throw;
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static string DoSomething()
{
   Console.WriteLine("execute sync");
   return "sync result";
}

public static async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Execute async");
   await Task.Delay(100);
   return "async result";
}


...

Console.WriteLine(await SomethingAsync(DoSomething));
Console.WriteLine(await SomethingAsync(DoSomethingAsync));
```

**Output**

```
Create
execute sync
Dispose
sync result
Create
Execute async
Dispose
async result
```

To add some more efficiencies you can elide wrappers

**Exmaple**

```
public static  ValueTask<T> SomethingAsync<T>(Func<T> callback)
{
   try
   {
      return SomethingAsync(() => new ValueTask<T>(callback()));
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return ValueTask.FromException<T>(e);
   }
}

public static ValueTask<T> SomethingAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> callback)
{
   try
   {
      return SomethingAsync(() => new ValueTask<T>(callback()));
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return ValueTask.FromException<T>(e);
   }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : `ValueTask.FromException` is only available for .NET 5.0+*</sub>

The benefits of this approach :

- Less allocations for the sync version of this method.
- There is no chance of a deadlock
- It doesn't block on async method
- It gives you a Value Task overload

The downsides are

- You need to wrap the *async task* in a *ValueTask*, though it's only a *stack allocation*
- You will need to create two overloads per method (in total three signatures)
- Neither version will can be awaited twice.
- The sync version is slightly slower as it creates a statemachine

Note : I personally have never had a need to do this, I would just create the two methods `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

---

**Additional resources**

- [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
- [Prefer ValueTask to Task, always; and don't await twice](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

Comment: *"The assumption is [...] awaiting the sync version of this call is not a problem for you."* <== This seems like a show-stopper for this solution, which is otherwise very interesting. The OP most probably needs the `SyncVer` because the calling site is not async. Otherwise why would they need it?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes if the OP wanted a non async method, then you are absolutely right, However, the use case would be if one wanted an overload and to reuse code (like within the using statement), minimal allocations and not blocking async methods. Truthfully though, I wouldn't do any of this really :) Also note, this is about 10 percent slower on the sync path, but half the allocations when an await is considered on the called method

Comment: `() =>` also allocates.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah i am not sure if there is a way to cache that. i guess not